# I can't upload files to a web page through code igniter

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, upload, privileges

I'm new in the use of code igniter, however I have been having a problem while trying to upload files to a certain directory.

You see, I've tested the page in localhost, and I have no problem in uploading files in that situation, however, whenever I try to run that on server I keep getting the message that:"the directory doesn't appear to be writable". If I change the directory privileges to 777, fixes the problem, however that is a bad practice while developing a web page, and I would like it to keep the privileges in 775 at the least.

I have also found out that the executing 'whoami' I get the username 'wwwrun' so, is it possible to change the configuration of code igniter so that it runs with an user that owns that directory?

I really hope you can help me with this problem since, I haven't found a clear solution since I don't know where to begin...

Answer (score 0):

you change the permssion before code igniter uploads, the folder should be owned by wwwrun and maybe in the wwwrun group, Maybe in the coders group ?

When its chowned to wwwrun having permission 700 or 750 will be fine

Comment: So, you can't change the user who executes codeigniter through configuration? because I have the user that owns that folder, however CI does not return That user when I ask execute whoami, and I'm trying to do that without modifying the server configuration.